# Android displaying textView instead of toast only showing last part of toast

Tags: java, android, json

I am already able to show the json splitted nicely in an toast like this: 
Key: Value
Key: Value

Defining the textview in the public class:

```
private TextView resultaat;
```

This is the declaration of my TextView:

```
resultaat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultaat);
```

This is the part where it make's the toast(s) and now the setText of the textView:

```
public void parseJson (String jsonString) throws JSONException{
    Toast.makeText(this, jsonString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    JSONObject obj=new JSONObject(jsonString);
    //Getting all the keys inside json object with key- pages
    Iterator<String> keys= obj.keys();
    while (keys.hasNext())
    {
        String keyValue = (String)keys.next();
        Toast.makeText(this, keyValue+":"+obj.getString(keyValue), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        resultaat.setText(keyValue+":"+obj.getString(keyValue));
    }

}
```

What i want it now just as it does with the toast show everytime key: value but with this line of code:

```
resultaat.setText(keyValue+":"+obj.getString(keyValue));
```

it only displays the last key: value of the json how can i make it that it will show all the key: value like the toast?

BTW this is an old post so dont watch the comments!!

Comment: Do you know how to use an `Intent` to pass information from one activity to another?

Comment: This is in a fragment which is inside `MainActivity`?

Comment: use `mEditor = shared.edit();` before another call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your code like this

```
while (keys.hasNext())
{
    String keyValue = (String)keys.next();
    Toast.makeText(this, keyValue+":"+obj.getString(keyValue), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    resultaat.setText( resultaat.getText().toString()+ keyValue+":"+obj.getString(keyValue));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this while saving the values.

```
btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (!validateIpAdres(ipadres.getText().toString())) {
            ipadres.setError("Geen geldig IP-adres");
            ipadres.requestFocus();
        } else if (!validatePoort(poort.getText().toString())) {
            poort.setError("Geen geldige Poort");
            poort.requestFocus();
        } else {
            //save the Ip-adres
            String IP = mIpAdres.getText().toString();
            shared.edit().putString("IP", IP).commit();

            //save the Poort
            String PORT = mPoort.getText().toString();
            shared.edit().putString("PORT", PORT).commit();
        }
    }
});
```

and when come back to mainActivity, use this in `onResume();`

```
String IP = shared.getString("IP", "no_ip");
String PORT = shared.getString("PORT", "no_port");
```

Comment: @Merijn Welcome to Android Development.

shared is the object of SharedPreferences. and you need to implement `onResume()`.

Tips:- Read about Activity Lifecycle and sharedPreferences and some basics too before code ...

Comment: @Merijn ok.. So first of all create an Object of `SharedPreferences shared = getSharedPreferences("MY_PREF", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);` in both activities and use it as i posted in answer.

Comment: what is the problem ? didn't you get the values?

Comment: ("IP", "no_ip") and ("PORT", "no_port") both have red lines and says: 'getString(java.lang.String)' in 'java.util.ResourceBundle' cannot be applied to '(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)'

Comment: check your `shared` object.. is it defined correctly ?

Comment: yeah in both classes i have this in the oncreate SharedPreferences shared = getSharedPreferences("MY_PREF", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

Comment: nope... from there it is not accessible in onResume unless you make it class level.. OKey.. So put this line just before both lines in `onResume()`.. it will be resolved.